# Facebook Graph Error: This api call does not support permalink tokens

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After successfully sharing a page on Facebook via the Android SDK I get a post id like this: UzpfSTEwMDAwODU3NTM4NTA5NjoxNDk2NTQ0NTc3MzA4MDQx

How can I validate this post on the server side via the Graph API?

Currently all I get is this error:

(#100) This api call does not support permalink tokens

Comment: I would report a bug about this in our [bug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Answer (score 2):

The post id `UzpfSTEwMDAwODU3NTM4NTA5NjoxNDk2NTQ0NTc3MzA4MDQx` is encoded to Base64 you should decode it.

Tried to decode it using https://www.base64decode.org/ and I got this `S:_I100008575385096:1496544577308041`. You could do a string manipulation and parse the postId to `100008575385096_1496544577308041`. And you could use it on the Graph API to get the post.

This link should help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html in decoding Base64 in Android.